# Why is installing a custom OS on an android phone that difficult?

Tags: system-installation, boot-loader, android, arm

From what I understand there should not be much of a problem installing the (arm supporting) Linux distribution of your choice on an Android device, once the bootloader is unlocked.

My thought is basically: **What is the difference between an android phone and some other arm computer once we unlocked the bootloader?**

There were some possible explanations coming to my mind:

1. The mainline Linux kernel doesn't support the hardware; some device drivers are only available on the kernel build by the manufacture. *But*, I find it hard to imagine that there is no hardware support in the default Linux kernel for almost a whole class of devices, especially since these kernel modules must exist since those devices all run Android.
2. Really unlocking the bootloader is an illusion, the control someone usually gains when he thinks he 'unlocked' the bootloader is still very limited. I must honestly say that my knowledge about bootloaders is of a very practical and limited nature, so I am not sure what to make of this theory.

*Please ignore all concerns regarding the usefulness of running something like Debian on your smartphone, I really only want to find out why it seems to be such a difficult thing to do.*

Comment: [How to boot Ubuntu persistent live USB on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/220678/218526)

Comment: [Bootloader/BIOS, flashing ROM and correlated risks. Why Android devices are more brickable than PCs?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205552/218526)

Answer (score 3):

Lots of devices in phones come with binary only drivers (modules), so you're exactly right. This is why Google wants to replace the Linux kernel with a stable API/ABI kernel of their own (Zircon) - it will allow you to keep your kernel up to date for much longer while using the same binary drivers.

Secondly, even when a certain device is known it may require a ton of quirks to function properly, for instance an audio codec on smartphones processes so many inputs and outputs (analog/digital/bluetooth/etc.), it may simply not work properly or work at all without a configuration file from the vendor.

Unlocking the bootloader does allow you to overwrite all the data on the internal storage but in most cases you cannot alter the vendor partition scheme.

In a summary installing a custom OS on a smartphone is not difficult, but it's extremely difficult to make everything work.